# Equation number placement

Tags: math-mode, formatting

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{equation}
  R_{jt,L} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccl} R_{jt}  & ; & \mbox{if $P_{jt-1} > P_{jt-1,L}$; } \\ 0 & ; & \mbox{$r_{ft}$ otherwise;} \end{array} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 +\hat{V}(x).
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The problem is, equation is not appearing  at the margin, as I have got for equation no.

The output is [image]

I want the equation no in the right side, as we get generally at the margin.

Comment: you're missing a `\right.` to match the `\left\{`.  what you really want is `amsmath`'s `cases` environment.

Comment: Each `\left` *requires* an accompanying `\right` in the same group. You don't have the latter, and you're probably looking for `\right.`

Comment: Please see the question. I have updated.

Comment: The EQ number IS on the right, what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: When I write only with `\begin equation`  I get generally  get equation 2 inch right away

Comment: Can you see the differences?

Comment: Placement is correct if you add the missing `\begin{document}` and `\right.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use package `mathtools`  which itself loads `amsmath` and fixes some bugs:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 R_{jt, L} = 
\begin{cases}
   R_{jt} & \text{;  if }P_{jt-1} > P_{jt-1,L}  \\ 
        0 & \text{; } r_{ft} \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 +\hat{V}(x).
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want both equations aligned to the `=` use:

```
\begin{align}
 R_{jt, L} &= 
\begin{cases}
   R_{jt} & \text{;  if }P_{jt-1} > P_{jt-1,L}  \\ 
        0 & \text{; } r_{ft} \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} \\[15pt]
%
\hat{H} &= - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 +\hat{V}(x).
\end{align}
```

[image]